# error in the SML of NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj

hello everyone I have this snippet of the code:

```
local
 fun NTimesF(f, n:int) = 
    if n = 1 then fn (x) => f(x)
    else fn (x) => f(NTimesF(f, n - 1)(x))
in  
 fun compList f n = if n = 0  then []
                    else (NTimesF(f, n)) :: (compList f n-1)
end;
```

I need to write program which receives some function f and integer n and produce list of functions such as `[f1, f2, ... fn] <- fn is the composition of the function n times` but every time I receive an error:

```
- stdIn:7.11-7.46 Error: operator and operand don't agree [literal]
  operator domain: ('Z -> 'Z) * ('Z -> 'Z) list
  operand:         ('Z -> 'Z) * int
  in expression:
    NTimesF (f,n) :: (compList f) n - 1
stdIn:6.6-7.46 Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [literal]
  expression:  int -> _ list
  result type:  int -> int
  in declaration:
    compList = (fn arg => (fn <pat> => <exp>))
-
```

can somebody please help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because function application has higher precedence than the `-` operator, `compList f n-1` is parsed as `(compList f n) - 1`, which is obviously not what you want.

You need to write `compList f (n-1)`.

Comment: thank You very much, how have You noticed it? Do familiar with ML?

Comment: @rookie: Yes, I'm familiar with ML (otherwise I wouldn't be browsing the sml tag ;-) ). Also the error message tells you where the error is and if you look closely it also tells you how the expression was parsed. So from there it's easy to find the error with a bit of experience.